# improve bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sensors

I have a quad core desktop, and i wanted to know the average temprature according to sensors. so i wrote this bash 1 liner.

```
echo `sensors -A | awk {'print $3'} | sed 's/+\|(crit\|0:\|°C//g'` |  awk '{print ($1 + $2 + $3 + $4)/4}'
```

but its not perfect I am sure. for example,  if the number of cores changes, my script will break, or just not be as accurate. How might I write a script that looks at the number or output values, and adjusts for number of cores?

as in (pseudo code ahead):

```
echo `sensors -A | awk {'print $3'} | sed 's/+\|(crit\|0:\|°C//g'` |  awk '{print ($n + $n+1 <=($number of cores)) )/($number of cores)}'
```

I hope that is human readable.
The output of   the first part is something like:

```
$  echo `sensors -A | awk {'print $3'} | sed 's/+\|(crit\|0:\|°C//g'`
31.0 31.0 26.0 27.0
```

can i get some pro-tips on getting average cpu temperature?

Comment: First things first: Ditch the `echo \`\``. It looks just plain ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
sensors -A | grep -oP '^Core.+?  \+\K\d+' | awk '{k+=$1}END{print k/NR}'
```

The grep will print only the relevant numbers (the spaces ensure that only the actual temperature is printed, not the critical or anything else) and the `awk` does the calculation. `NR` is the number of lines so that will work if the number of cores changes.

Answer (score 6):

Using the "raw output" mode of `sensors` for easier scripting:

```
-u    Raw output. This mode is suitable for debugging  and  for  post-
      processing  of  the  output  by  scripts. It is also useful when
      writing a configuration file because  it  shows  the  raw  input
      names which must be referenced in the configuration file.
```

For example:

```
$ sensors -Au
coretemp-isa-0000
Physical id 0:
  temp1_input: 63.000
  temp1_max: 85.000
  temp1_crit: 105.000
  temp1_crit_alarm: 0.000
Core 0:
  temp2_input: 51.000
  temp2_max: 85.000
  temp2_crit: 105.000
  temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000
```

Armed with such nicely labeled fields, one can construct a far simpler awk command:

```
sensors -Au | awk '/temp.*_input/{temp += $2; count += 1} END {print temp/count}'
```

Essentially, for each `temp.*_input` field, add the temperature and increment a count, then at the end, print the total divided by the count.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of processors using

```
grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: The `nproc` command could do that job.